# remove all local users with UID higher than 1000

Tags: bash, userdel

i thought i might just try to simplify the question. trying to get a bash script to query for any uid higher than 1000 and delete.

if uid > 1000 userdel uid
else ignore
quit

Comment: This is not a code writing service, where you post your requirements and language of choice and some code monkey churns out code to meet them. A *couple hours* isn't much effort at all. Try harder.

Comment: sorry ken. i didn't mean to offend anyone. was just looking for help. i didn't ask anyone to write code for me.  just point in the right direction

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 while IFS=":" read -r user x uid x; do [[ $uid -gt 1000 ]] && echo userdel -r "$user"; done </etc/passwd
```

If everythings looks fine, remove `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
perl -F: -lanE 'say $F[0] if $F[2] > 1000' /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 echo userdel -r
```

or

```
awk -F':' '$3 > 1000 {print $1}' /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 echo userdel -r
```